# User Management System in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

The requirements of most web applications regarding the management of users are fairly common:

- A user registers himself
- Receives an email for confirmation
- Requests a forgotten password
- An admin person assigns a role to the user, etc.

Is there a node.js/express.js project that has already implemented the flow and is customizable?

Passport.js allows the application to only authenticate but not perform the functions listed above. I have seen Drywall. It uses MongoDB.
I am looking for a module that lets me customize the user storage mechanism as well, so that I can use my own MySQL DB to store users.

ASP .NET provides such features in the membership module and also lets developers customize it completely. Do we have something for Node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [sails framework](http://sailsjs.org/) and there are some packages that integrates with sails. For authentication i found this package: https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth, maybe it help you.

Comment: I tried `sails-generate-auth` but I liked `sails-permissions` better.

Answer (score 1):

To build on [Victor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286937/victor) answer, there is a comprehensive user/role management system for express called [**sails-permissions**](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions) that is based on [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use Drywall and customize it to use mySQL. It's uncommon to use mySQL for node.js as you know already.

Maybe this article will help you with the mySQL integration:

http://teknosains.com/i/simple-crud-nodejs-mysql